# Alternative to compile python for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ in order to get the LIBs

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling

I have a C++ wrapper for a Python module. In order to compile my C++ code, I need the libs of Python. Code compiles on my installation Ubuntu, on g++. Now I want to compile

```
$> make CXX=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

1. Got arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ on my path.
2. Got all the standard libs and includes for ARM,
3. Except python libs for ARM.

So, AFAIK I need to compile Python source code for ARM.
Maybe using this [link](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-ARM-cross-compiling-howto.html)?

Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a more recent link for [cross compiling for ARM](http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html) (and PPC), but if you're not using something like OpenEmbedded or Buildroot (or whatever else to make a complete embedded distribution) to build all your environment, you'll have to use those tutorials (OpenEmbedded, Buildroot & others are using those methods and patches to cross compile python).

Comment: In other words, yes, I have to compile. This http://rharon.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux-friendlyarm/ was the one that made it for me although it is similar to the link posted above. (however the link above has many more patches to python versions). I have used a different ARM compiler, I just switched the 'ppc-6xx' with the name of the compiler. Some points that made me stuck for a while: using the unix patch tool - but it auto-create backups when something goes wrong. Differing which options regard the build machine and which regard the target machine.